# Trying to convert first symbol of string to int, getting weird value

Tags: c#, string, integer

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str_val = "8584348,894";
    //int prefix = Convert.ToInt32(str_val[0]); //prefix = 56 O_o
    //int prefix = (int)str_val[0]; //what, again 56? i need 8!
    int prefix = Convert.ToInt32("8"); //at least this works -_-
}
```

Any idea how to convert first symbol to right numeric value?

Comment: It is finding the ascii value of the character instead, in case you wondered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use:

```
Convert.ToInt32(str_val[0]);
```

then you are actually calling the overload:

```
Convert.ToInt32(char val);
```

which gives the Unicode/Ascii number of character being passed as a parameter.

If you want to convert first character, you need to force it to be a string type:

```
Convert.ToInt32(str_val.Substring(0, 1));
```

This way you call the overload:

```
Convert.ToInt32(string val);
```

which actually do what you want (convert string value to int value that this string represents).

Answer (score 3):

Your trying to parse a string but passing in a char. Convert the character to a string first.

```
int prefix = Convert.ToInt32(str_val[0].ToString());
```

So the character value of 8 is the ASCII value 56, what you want to do is inteprete the value as a string rather than an ASCII Value. By using the .ToString() method you are converting the character into a null terminated string, which can be read by the ToInt32 method.

Answer (score 2):

By doing this way `Convert.ToInt32(str_val[0])` you are reading the character at a index of the string that converts the char to int. the int is the ascii for it

Comment: i didn't set you -1, it was someone else :P i always set +1 to everyone who answer

Comment: i did :] but now reverted as you included this "the int is the ascii for it" explanation in your answer. :] regards.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek yes because typed it to quickly to get the answer first, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Like Bridge mentioned, it's getting the ASCII value. When you use the indexer on the string class to get just a character, it returns it as a char. If you read the [char documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) you'll see that it is internally stored as a numeric UTF-16 value. It also has implicit conversions to and from most numeric types, which extract the UTF-16 value, or convert the numeric form into the character form. That's what you're doing.

What you mean to do is parse it as an int, not get the numeric representation of the UTF-16 value. That's where the Convert answers all come in.

Answer (score 1):

```
Int32.Parse(str_val[0])
```

Will give you number in string.